# Lost Samsung Galaxy S6 help!

Tags: lost-phone

My friend has not been able to find her Galaxy S6 which went missing on Saturday night at a dinner party. Many of us rang the phone on that evening whilst at the house but it was on silent. We thought it would just turn up in the morning and didn't think too much of it. Unfortunately, it has not.

Now things are starting to get a little ugly with airs of suspicions and the possibility that someone has taken it or hidden it etc. This has come about as she has tried to locate it using "my account google" etc and that has shown the phone was last "synched" at 11.22am yesterday morning. The last time she rang it was at 9.30am yesterday morning and it was dead. With it saying the phone was synched this has now led her to think it has been switched on I guess...is this the case or does the phone still synch somehow even if switched off, dead??

It's not a great situation at the moment and any help greatly received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm still trying to determine what the sync is. Cuz on my device it shows *part synced feb. 25* even though I just synced it now. So I'm not sure exactly what that means, but I think it's safe to say that whatever it means, the phone has to be in for that action to happen. When checking on find my device, did you make sure that her device is selected and not yours?

Answer (score 0):

If the device has been taken or lost and is off, there's not much you can do.

If you think it may have been switched on, there is a section [on your Google Account](http://myaccount.google.com) that will allow you to track/lock/call/sign out of your phone. More options can be explored on [Google's help page for lost devices](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7177579?visit_id=1-636560461745214582-2993125644&p=lda-friend&rd=1).

There's also a setting to `Ring the device` when you select `Locate` from the last link, which will ring the device at full volume for five minutes, even if it was set to silent.